# How to access mysql databases inside docker from a SQL GUI?

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I am using [vessel](https://vessel.shippingdocker.com/) to run my Laravel project.

As I understand it basically simply creates a put-together docker image of my laravel project with mysql and everything.

Now since its running in docker, is it possible for me to access the mySQL databases with datagrip or tableplus on my host machine?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to expose a port via docker.  If you dont,you will have port 3306 which can be accessed via the local containers but if you bind port 3307:3306 for instance you can connect to mysql locally on 3307

Answer (score -1):

you will need to connect to MySQL server using the docker containers IP that can be found using docker inspect.

This can also help you:
https://towardsdatascience.com/connect-to-mysql-running-in-docker-container-from-a-local-machine-6d996c574e55

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP addresses don't work except on one very specific Docker/host OS setup.  If the caller is using MacOS, or Windows, or Docker Toolbox, or is on another host, this won't work.